# How to remove background color from this svg photo in css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I got this svg pattern from an opensource so they already got it coded, but I want to customize it where the background is transparent.

I've struggled just to remove the background, how can I do that?

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFutm.png)

and this is the code from the opensource

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg id='patternId' width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><defs><pattern id='a' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='40' height='20' patternTransform='scale(1) rotate(0)'><rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='hsla(0,0%,100%,1)'/><path d='M-4.798 13.573C-3.149 12.533-1.446 11.306 0 10c2.812-2.758 6.18-4.974 10-5 4.183.336 7.193 2.456 10 5 2.86 2.687 6.216 4.952 10 5 4.185-.315 7.35-2.48 10-5 1.452-1.386 3.107-3.085 4.793-4.176'  stroke-width='3.5' stroke='hsla(0, 0%, 92%, 1)' fill='none'/></pattern></defs><rect width='800%' height='800%' transform='translate(0,0)' fill='url(%23a)'/></svg>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `<rect>` portion of the svg. Being that it has a width and height of 100%, it is likely the background. It has a `fill` property. Change that to none.

```
<rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='none'/>
```

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg id='patternId' width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><defs><pattern id='a' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='40' height='20' patternTransform='scale(1) rotate(0)'><rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='none'/><path d='M-4.798 13.573C-3.149 12.533-1.446 11.306 0 10c2.812-2.758 6.18-4.974 10-5 4.183.336 7.193 2.456 10 5 2.86 2.687 6.216 4.952 10 5 4.185-.315 7.35-2.48 10-5 1.452-1.386 3.107-3.085 4.793-4.176'  stroke-width='3.5' stroke='hsla(0, 0%, 92%, 1)' fill='none'/></pattern></defs><rect width='800%' height='800%' transform='translate(0,0)' fill='url(%23a)'/></svg>");
```